# minecraft turns off router

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

my son has a laptop which is connected to the router with a cat5e lead, after some time, maybe 10 minutes or even an hour the internet is turned off at the router, why does this happen, all devices in the house, laptops, tablets, phones cannot access the internet using wifi or direct link to the router...... can someone explain this to us...we have had upc here a dozen times.. they tell us that the broadband is ok.....

Comment: Have you tried wireless, or resetting the router?

Comment: How did you determine that Minecraft is causing the problem?

Comment: This question would likely be better placed on http://superuser.com/ as it does not appear to have anything to do with gaming.

Answer (score 4):

The recommendation by Phaeze is more likely to get you to your answer.  On a side note, it's likely that Minecraft doesn't necessarily have anything to do with your problem since the time frame is anywhere between 10-60 minutes.  It's probably just coincidental.

If your router is a combo modem/router that your ISP provides, it could be faulty.

If it's a separate router, try bypassing the router when you lose connection and connect directly into the modem to see if you're able to hit websites.  This will likely be a router issue.  Depending on if it's ISP property, you'll need to get them to replace it or you'll need to purchase it yourself.

But if the router is physically shutting down (no lights), chances are the router is just dieing.

I'd recommend following up with [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) though for more detailed troubleshooting if needed.